# CheckNumeric value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function for checking text box value for entering only integer values.

```
function CheckNumeric(e) {
    if (window.event) // IE 
    {
        if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { // Fire Fox
        if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this function textbox can accept `0` for value and reject any character.

Now I want to change this function to reject `0` if it is entered as the first character.

For example reject this: `010` and accept this: `10`

Comment: It looks like you're using inline JavaScript for validating the input. Since you're using jQuery you could use it to bind the submit/keypress/whatever event instead and get rid of the IE-specific code.

Comment: One more question here. When you are calling CheckNumber function?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check `if (e.keyCode == 48 && input.value.length == 0)` then `return false;`

`input` is your text box element.

something like this

```
if (window.event) // IE 
    {
        if (((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) || (e.keyCode == 48 && input.value.length == 0)) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and it should be

```
(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && e.keyCode != 8)
```

instead of

```
(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8)
```